# How do I make Bash' tab complete automatically cycle through options OSX

Tags: macos, bash, autocomplete, sh

Currently when I'm in my home folder and I want to `cd` into Documents I type `cd D` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Bash shows me the list of folders that match `D`.

What I want to occur is when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, bash autocompletes with the first option that matches what I've put in and each time I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it cycles through to the next option.

Is there any way to do this? I thought for sure my copy of Bash on my old Ubuntu box had this feature.

Comment: This certainly isn't the default behavior for bash on Ubuntu, although it is in the Windows `cmd` shell.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/59175/is-there-a-way-to-make-bash-more-tab-friendly

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes! I found the answer to the question at the following [link at MacWorld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050904022246573)

put the following in .bashrc or .bash_login

```
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
```

Comment: That should work. I just ended up using the answer from the link Barton posted.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work like zsh? For example, zsh will give you a list of the possible completions after two tabs and then it will begin to cycle through them.

Comment: Let me know if you found a way to do it minhaz1

Comment: I was looking for it ages.

Comment: Let's pretend you are using `cd` and `menu-complete` and cycling over directories. What key do you press to "pick" that directory and start cycling the contents of that directory? Is there another thing to set/bind?

Comment: a few years late to the party, but to "pick" that directory just type / and then start tabbing again. its ok if you end up two slashes, it will work fine. if you don't like that you can type / and backspace for the same effect.

Comment: @minhaz1 The closest I found is bind some key to `glob-complete-word` to list options and use `TAB` only when needed

Comment: @minhaz1 You can also unset TAB's binding from menu-complete to the default behavior and it will first show options and only on the second tab starts cycling them